# ArcGIS Portal error "Accessing Data failed"

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, map-service, arcgis-portal

In ArcGIS Server, I have published a dynamic map service, but in ArcGIS portal, while accessing the same map service using add data option "Add layer from web" I am getting an error `Accessing Data failed` while loading the service. In service pooling, I have set the service timeout to 300 seconds (5 minutes).

I am not getting any error while fetching data from the attribute table of source MXD and querying from the published service.

Answer (score 0):

in the webmap, try changing your URL from http to https (or vice versa).  Try accessing the service from the hosting server.  Make sure that the service is started.  Try accessing the service in a REST service.  If you published with feature access, change "MapServer" in the URL to "FeatureServer".

Comment: I am using https for rest service and service is in started status.